# How can I achieve a margin-left with a div with float: right?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/hga7Lxt8/1/

```
float: right;
margin-left: 10px;
```

There is no margin to the left of the orange-red box (the top borders of the rows reach right up to it), even though it has such style attribute. What is wrong?

Comment: It does work fine. Note that the rows are continuing behind the DIV, they do not end where the .right div starts.  You will see what I mean when you change margin-left: 10px; to margin: 10px;

Comment: Why do they continue behind the DIV and how can I prevent this?

Comment: You can see the real problem when you apply a semi-transparent background-color. http://jsfiddle.net/hga7Lxt8/2/

Comment: Margin-right on the rows would fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the real problem when you [apply a semi-transparent background-color](http://jsfiddle.net/hga7Lxt8/2).

What you need to understand is that **content** floats around a floating element, not containing boxes (unless they also float or have a display property set to something other than `block`).

You fix it by setting `margin-right: 110px;` on your `.row`:

http://jsfiddle.net/hga7Lxt8/4/

What you want to achieve can only be [faked](http://jsfiddle.net/hga7Lxt8/4/) and would not "work" if your floating element has any transparency (or box-shadows).

Answer (score 0):

The row elements are continuing behind the orangered box. Try:

```
 .right {
     float: right; 
     width: 100px; 
     height: 100px; 
     background: orangered;
 }
 .row {
     border-top: 1px solid;    
     overflow: auto;
     margin-right: 110px;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thrb5936/

Comment: Forgot to say that I want the rows to stretch all the way to the right below the red box.

Comment: That's not possible using CSS. You can have only rectangle-sized boxes in CSS.